# Populate values in View Model List Object

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a problem where I am unable to get values filled by user in my view to List defined in ViewModel.

I have View where in some fields will be filled manually as:

```
S.No   StyleName    JobType    Quantity
1      ABC          Repair     2
2      XYZ          Wash       3
```

My `ViewModel` is as below:

```
    public class IssueViewModel
    {          
        public List<OrderItem> Items { get; set; }              
    }
```

My `OrderItem` is defined as below

```
    public class OrderItem
    {
        public int OrderItemId { get; set; }
        public string StyleName { get; set; }
        public string JobType{ get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }

    }
```

Now problem is how to link this ViewModel List to View to get the Values in my `Items` list to be saved in DB.

Its working fine if I define separate Lists for StyleName, JobType and Quantity. In that case my view is something like below:

```
<table id="theTable">
  <tr>
    <th>Sr.No</th>
    <th>Style Name</th>
    <th>JobType</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>
          @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.StyleName)
            @*<input type = "text" style="border:0px;" value = "" />*@
    </td>         
    <td>
          @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.JobType)
           @*<input type = "text" style="border:0px;" value = "" />*@
    </td>
    <td>
          @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Quantity)
            @*<input type = "text" style="border:0px;" value = "" />*@
    </td>    
  </tr>
</table>
```

If I use above I have to read 3 different loops to get values. I understand this is not right approach.

I know for displaying we use for loop but here I need to accept values filled by user. I searched a lot for this but didn't find any solution. Please advise. Thanks

Comment: You can use a feature called EditorTemplates: http://coding-in.net/asp-net-mvc-3-how-to-use-editortemplates/

Comment: Do you want the code i.e., **Controller** Code for how to get the `Items` and to save in *Database*?

Comment: @SoftwareFactor Thanks for the link. Its a nice tutorial but being a beginner I am finding it hard to implement. Still trying though..

Comment: @prakash2089 I do not want the Controller Code but the html(View) code to get values entered by User in my Controller. From Controller I can save the values in DB. Its just that I am unable to get values from View to Controller in Array List.

Answer (score 0):

Create an editor template for `OrderItem`, where you have textboxes for each property, and then in your main view, just use `Html.EditorForModel()`, which will generate markup according to the editor template for each property in the model, and if the property is a list, then for each item inside that list. You don't need to manually loop anything anywhere.

Comment: Thanks. I tried as suggested but seems not doing it right way. Still trying though..